# Excel Sum Values for Criteria, Criteria and Values in Same Row

Tags: excel, sum

I have strings and number values in the same row. I need to search for a given string in the row, which might be found multiple times, and return the sum of the values, which are immediately to the cell to the right of the string. E.g.,

string1 value1 string1 value2 string2 value3

If I am looking for string1, I need to return the sum of value1 and value2. I do not have the option of putting the strings and values in separate rows or columns to make this easier.

Update:

My selection is currently the entire row (not just a range within the row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF` with the ranges offset by 1 cell from each other, e.g. if your data is in A2:Z2 then try this formula

`=SUMIF(A2:Y2,"string1",B2:Z2)`

Comment: Excellent. This will get me enough of the way there that I can modify some VBA to make it work. See the updated question. I'll score this as the answer if there is nothing better.

Comment: However, if my selection is the entire row (e.g., "2:2"), how can I get an adjacent cell?

Comment: You can use 2:2 for the criteria range and then just the start cell of the sum range, e.g. `=SUMIF(2:2,"string1",B2)`

Comment: Marked as answered, because that is technically the answer that makes it work.